# XML parsing from URL in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to parse the XML value from an URL.I parsed some of the XML from URL and it is working fine.But I am facing the issue with the following XML only.

```
<state>
<pincode>600001</pincode>
<pincode>600002</pincode>
<pincode>600003</pincode>
<pincode>600004</pincode>
<pincode>600005</pincode>
<pincode>600006</pincode>
<pincode>600007</pincode>
<pincode>600008</pincode></state>
```

I need to read all the value of pincode from XML.

I will try parse with the below sample code.

```
public static ArrayList<Pojo_spinner> PINCODE_PARSER(Context context,
        String pincode_xml) {
    ArrayList<Pojo_spinner> pincode = new ArrayList<Pojo_spinner>();
    String xmlRecords = pincode_xml;
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));

        Document doc = db.parse(is);

        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("state");

        Pojo_spinner _states = new Pojo_spinner("", "");

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

            NodeList board_name1 = element.getElementsByTagName("pincode");
            Element line = (Element) board_name1.item(0);
            String sc_name = Utils_edu_grid
                    .getCharacterDataFromElement(line);

            System.out.println("://pincode name" + sc_name + " ");
            _states = new Pojo_spinner(sc_name, sc_name);
            pincode.add(_states);

        }
        return pincode;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pincode;
}
```

Help me to do this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: So how far have you got so far? Please ask a *specific* question.

Comment: It is extremely easy to do that. Take a look at XML parsers such as JSoup and you'll figure it out instantly